# Exporting FLA to FLV

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv

Can I export the contents of FLA to FLV using Flash CS 3?

I have a project where the client wants a generic media container so they can possibly load user supplied content. The content could be slideshows, or video etc.

A possible solution is to restrict the media to only FLV. So that I don't have to deal with the situation where a swf might have a lot of embedded animations etc. I need deterministic performance from whatever I load in, as the machine the app is running on is being pushed to it's limits as it stands.

But how would I go about converting a simple slideshow made in a FLA into a FLV?

Comment: From FlashPlayer 9,0,115 onwards you should probably be using F4V instead of FLV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export to a movie (.mov, .avi, etc...) and then convert that to FLV.
File > Export > Export Movie...
I think CS3 already has the feature of exporting the movie correctly (with actionscript, user interaction, etc...); if not, CS4 definitely does.

Answer (score 0):

That project is really risky. You should say that you need convert swf to flv. This is a bigger problem. If you are worried about performance (and safety of your app), I advise you to allow only video content and convert it to flv.

Comment: The onus is on the supplier on the content. I will only deal with flv on my end. I just want to create some dummy flv content for debugging